# Find top 5 famous people

Tags: sql

I have a case in hand where I need to find the top 5 people with most likes on their posts overall.

Here's the schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    url VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);

CREATE TABLE likes (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    contents VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    post_id INTEGER REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    comment_id INTEGER REFERENCES comments(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    --  either associated with post or comment  --
    CHECK(
        COALESCE((post_id)::boolean::integer, 0) +
        COALESCE((comment_id)::boolean::integer, 0) = 1
    ),
    -- user can like post/comment once --
    UNIQUE (user_id, post_id, comment_id)
);
```

#### My Attempts

Both are giving different outputs, not sure which one is correct. Also, I would appreciate an ideal (scalable) solution for this:

##### 1.

```sql
WITH FAMOUS AS (
    SELECT likes.id, users.username AS username, users.id AS user_id 
    FROM likes 
    JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = likes.post_id
    JOIN users ON users.id = likes.user_id 
    WHERE likes.comment_id IS null
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num, username FROM FAMOUS
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5;
```

##### 2.

```sql
WITH LIKES_DATA AS (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS num_likes_per_post FROM likes 
    WHERE likes.comment_id IS NULL 
    GROUP BY post_id
) 
SELECT users.username, SUM(num_likes_per_post) as num_likes 
FROM LIKES_DATA
JOIN posts ON posts.id = LIKES_DATA.post_id
JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id
GROUP BY users.username
ORDER BY num_likes DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: `Not sure which one is correct` Well, I suggest you start there

Comment: How do I check which one is correct? The dataset is huge.

Comment: Please tag only the database system you're actually using.

Comment: Start with a smaller data set

Answer (score 0):

I simply do not understand the thought process for the second query.

Based on your description, I think just using `JOIN`s and `GROUP BY` is sufficient:

```
SELECT u.username AS username, u.id AS user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM likes l JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.user_id = l.post_id JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = l.user_id 
WHERE likes.comment_id IS NULL   -- don't know what this is for
GROUP BY u.username, u.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```